# static resources behind a reverse proxy server

Tags: web-server, reverse-proxy, node.js

Two localhost web servers are developed separately without the knowledge of each other and proxy server. Both setup using NodeJS and Express.js

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend'));
```

From these two servers I have two sets of static resources, for instance found in a HTML file

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>`

Now I have to setup a proxy server at `www.proxy.com`. Two web servers can be accessed by

1. `www.proxy.com/web1` -> `localhost:4000`
2. `www.proxy.com/web2` -> `localhost:4001`

This is done using NodeJS and http-proxy:

```
app.all("/web1*", (req, res) => {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/\/web1/g, "");
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: "http://localhost:4000"});
});

app.all("/web2*", (req, res) => {
    req.url = req.url.replace(/\/web2/g, "");
    apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: "http://localhost:4001"});
});
```

To have the static resources loaded correctly, the hard way is to change it all to match with the new url assignment, for instance

`<script type="text/javascript" src="`**web1/**`js/index.js"></script>`

But is there a better solution without changing url of all static resources?

Comment: Using subdomains to separate the apps instead of virtual directories would make it much easier.

Comment: True, but Im exploring the possibility to have it under a same domain name

Comment: I wanted to launch multiple servers on a same machine. So reverse proxy is necessary